# How to install library PHPJ/PHPJ to codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, composer-php

I'am using PHP and I want to implement arraycopy to my PHP Code

Here's the code from Java that I want to implement in my PHP

```
import java.lang.*;

public class SystemDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int arr1[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
      int arr2[] = { 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
    
      // copies an array from the specified source array
      System.arraycopy(arr1, 0, arr2, 0, 3);
      System.out.print("array2 = ");
      System.out.print(arr2[0] + " ");
      System.out.print(arr2[1] + " ");
      System.out.print(arr2[2] + " ");
      System.out.print(arr2[3] + " ");
      System.out.print(arr2[4] + " ");
      System.out.print(arr2[5] + " ");
   }
}
```

And I found a solution to use arraycopy in PHP from this [link](https://hotexamples.com/examples/phpj.lang/System/arraycopy/php-system-arraycopy-method-examples.html) and those solution referencing from this [github repo](https://github.com/PHPJ/PHPJ) . But I'm confused how to install this library on my codeigniter project.

Comment: This is unfinished and abandoned project, why would you want to use it?

Comment: Cause there's no other library like this project. I only need to use the arraycopy function from that library.

Comment: You can achieve the same with `array_slice($arr1, 0, 3) + $arr2`, you don't need java-like library to do one simple operation on array.

Comment: If for whatever reason you really wanted to only use [that specific function](https://github.com/PHPJ/PHPJ/blob/52fa760ce9c9ea4c221685e236e8b0eaebb4e8fb/src/Lang/System.php#L24), just bring the code over.

Comment: Please share more details. What do you want to achieve? It should be pretty simple to either write the code on your own, or install the given package through `composer`

Comment: @NicoHaase I want to use arraycopy function on my PHP project and bit confused to write those code from library, I think it's more easy to install on composer than write those code from library to my code because I am new to programming

Comment: And what's the problem in installing it through Composer? What have you tried to make it work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I dont know how to install those library via composer. Stuck at how to install those library using composer on my project

Comment: Can u give me step by step install those library via composer? It's gonna save my day @NicoHaase

Comment: Is there anything not working when using `composer install` like with every other library? Please edit your question to contain all attempts to resolve the problem